# Content will only show when delayed

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem when loading content into a div via Ajax.
I start with opening a dialogbox when I click on a button. The dialog box loads in a php file.
Right after the code for the dialog box I placed some code to load certain content into a div in that php file. My code:

```
function edit(serverpage, persoonid)
{
   $(".opendg").dialog(
    {
        open:function ()
        {
            $(this).load('/location/php/' + serverpage);
        },
        title: 'Change!',
        autoOpen: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        height: 335,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        close: function(){},
        buttons:
            {
                "Change": function()
                {
                    sendedit(serverpage, persoonid);
                    return;
                },
                "Cancel": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
    });
    xmlhttp = ajaxFunction();
    if (xmlhttp)
    {
        var url = "/location/php/" + serverpage;
        var pagelength = serverpage.length;
        var value = serverpage.substr(0,pagelength - 4);
        var params = "edit=" + value + "&id=" + persoonid;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
               if(xmlhttp.responseText != '')
               {
                value = value + 'form';
                alert('test');
                document.getElementById(value).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send(params);
    }
}
```

As you can see I placed an alert just before sending the responseText to the div.
I did this because without the alert I get an empty form!
The first time I open the dialog box I see nothing. After reopening I see a short flash of the content I want, but disappears in milliseconds.

The code which generates the content:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['edit'] == 'editpersoneel')
    {
        //Query run here to get the results
        echo '<form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first">
                        Location: 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="'.$result['location'].'" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="first">
                        phonenumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value= "'.$result[phonenumber'].'" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>';
    }
    ?>
<div id="editpersoneelform"></div>
```

I tried solving this with the $(document).ready statement from jQuery, but didn't work in any order.
I think the problem is that the div is unknown (somehow) to Ajax when sending the content, yet I do get a result.

So My question is:
- Why does my code work when I place an alert in it? (I only have to open the dialog once here)
- Why does my content get loaded and unloaded one millisecond thereafter? And why did I had to open the dialog twice?

**UPDATE**
When I place the alert after sending the responseText I have to open the dialog twice before I get to see the alertbox.

**UPDATE 2**
The code that calls the event:

```
<div class="jbutton">
    <a onclick="edit(\'editpersoneel.php\',\''.$b['id'].'\')">Adjust</a>
</div>
```

This button is placed inside a jquery-ui-accordion.

Comment: if you are using jquery, use `$.ajax`

Comment: @experimentX : I cannot since it is a schoolproject :), I need to use Ajax this way (outside jquery)... But thanks for the hint!

Comment: please also post your html code (if there is) and the event that fires up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why so complicated call of ajax and parsing of value from serverpage, but maybe You have one JS code for more than one edit function at more places... But to the point:

It looks like You don't have Your `<div id="editpersoneelform"></div>` inside the HTML from where the AJAX is called...

Lets suppose You have similar HTML file (I recommend using of jQuery at least for working with elements when You need the AJAX to be called in raw way):

```
<div id="editpersoneelform"></div>
<div class="jbutton">
    <a onclick="edit(\'editpersoneel.php\',\''.$b['id'].'\')">Adjust</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(serverpage, persoonid) {
        $(".opendg").dialog({
            open:function () {
                $(this).load('/location/php/' + serverpage);
            },
            title: 'Change!',
            autoOpen: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            height: 335,
            width: 650,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            close: function(){},
            buttons: {
                "Change": function() {
                    sendedit(serverpage, persoonid);
                    return;
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        xmlhttp = ajaxFunction();
        if (xmlhttp) {
            var url = "/location/php/" + serverpage;
            var pagelength = serverpage.length;
            var value = serverpage.substr(0,pagelength - 4);
            var params = "edit=" + value + "&id=" + persoonid;
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText != '') {
                        value = value + 'form';
                        alert(value);
                        $('div#'+value).html(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(params);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and then You have Your PHP file that is called by AJAX:

```
<?php
if($_POST['edit'] == 'editpersoneel') {
    //Query run here to get the results
    $form = '<form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="first">Location: </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="'.$result['location'].'" /></td>
                <td class="first">phonenumber</td>
                <td><input type="text" value= "'.$result[phonenumber'].'" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>';
    echo $form;
}
?>
```

If You want to load AJAX response to a certain element, that element has to be recent in the code from where the AJAX is called.

Try this and let us know if You'd succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I didn't got it worked. Still same issues. Also <div id="editpersoneelform"></div> is on a different page then 
<div class="jbutton">
    <a onclick="edit(\'editpersoneel.php\',\''.$b['id'].'\')">Adjust</a>
</div>  The first div is on editpersoneel.php and the second (with the call) is on personeel.php

Comment: Yes, and that is what I point out - the <div id="editpersoneelform"></div> must be on the same page where the AJAX call (so <a onclick=...>) is...

Comment: I tried putting it on the same page, just as your code implied, but couldn't get it work. I'll try a few things more with your example, I'll let you know.

Comment: Maybe If you could provide all of the files got involved in this I could help better... Upload the files somewhere and provide a links for them (not zipped, in readable way in browser)... Maybe there is other problem...

Comment: I got it working, yet it triggered an other problem, which is quite easy to solve I think, yet I do not succeed :(. When clicking the link I do get the data I want, but the data also appears on the page where the link (and also the div) is located. When I close the dialog and reopen it, the content disappears from the page into the dialog. So it does work, but not on the first click. How to solve this?